# Drawing Direction Fields Online

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, online-resources

I am looking for a convenient and free online tool for plotting Direction Fields and Solution Curves of Ordinary Differential Equations. I tried the "[Slope Field Plotter](https://www.geogebra.org/m/W7dAdgqc)" on Geogebra; it worked tolerably well with direction fields, but for solution curves, some funny thing happens like this:

[image]

My Questions:

1. Why does the solution curve appear to be very different from circles?
2. Is there any alternative online free resources that will do a better job on this?

**Edit:**

I would love to use [WolframaAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) for this, if it works. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: The curves for the solution are scripted. GeoGebra does it well, but it doesn't draw the solutions directly, it needs commands on how to do it. I can link a good GeoGebra sheet for ODE's. I'll do later...

Comment: Thanks for the comment! May I know what you mean by "scripted"?

Comment: Sorry, better said "you need a lot of construction steps". :)

Comment: Thanks @RafaBudría! I found it works well with other equations such as $y'=y^2+xy$; not sure why it does not do $y'=-x/y$ well.

Comment: I am checking that particular slope field.

Comment: @Zuriel: I bet it is having trouble due to the line $y=0$. The direction field lines are correct.

Comment: @Moo, is there any way to fix the problem, either using the same "Slope Field Plotter" or a different one?

Comment: Thanks @Moo. I would much prefer some free online alternative. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: [This one](https://www.geogebra.org/m/PcGZczvR) works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this tool:

https://www.bluffton.edu/homepages/facstaff/nesterd/java/slopefields.html

Found it from the Wikipedia slope field page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command streamplot in wolframalpha like this:

streamplot[{1-x^2+y,1+x-y^2},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]

where in the example above

$\dot{x}=1-x^2+y$ and $\dot{y}=1+x-y^2$

and the plot range is $x,y \in [-3,3]$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How to put in equation like $y'=-x/y$? Using streamplot[{1,-x/y},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]?

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $x$, i.e. $y=y(x)$? If so, then your system is 1-dimensional. Or is your system 2-dimensional with $x=x(t), y=y(t)$ and $\dot{x}=?, \dot{y}=-x/y$?

Comment: It is one dimensional; that is, $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: In that case, then your vector field will be on the real line, not on a plane. You could use streamplot[{0,-x/y},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}] to visualize it, where every vertical line will give you the vector field for a given constant $x$. Alternatively, you can solve the ODE directly and plot the solutions for different initial conditions $y_0$ vs $t$ as in the last plot here: [WolframAlpha solve y'=-x/t](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x'%3D-t%2Fx)